# uploading files to web directory with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a simple uploading application from a web page:localhost/test.html. I am getting these errors:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(test/Blue hills.jpg): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test.html on line 11

and

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php376.tmp'
>   to 'test/Blue hills.jpg' in C:\wamp\www\test.html on line 11

Here is my code

```
<html>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.html" method="POST">
    Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
<html>

<?php

$target = "test/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
$ok=1;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else {
  echo "Uploading Error.";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the directory `test` doesn't exist. Add these lines to your code.

```
if (file_exists('test/')) echo 'Ok it wasn\'t that';
else echo 'Um, create a directory called test here: '.dirname(__FILE__);
```

Comment: Thanks I tested it and it said there was no directory.but shouldn't a file work in the same way ie. /test.html

Comment: scratch that- I see now it has to be a folder. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the a `test/` directory exists in the directory where your script is located, then you can use

```
$out = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $out);
```

Comment: Thanks @bborisovs. This also has a predictable behavior instead of relying on `getcwd()`...

Answer (score 0):

Change directory permissions (CHMOD) to `777` via your FTP client (read,write,execute for owner,group,public).